# Xcode error while validation - “Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5”

Tags: storyboard, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, launchimage

Starting Titanium SDK 5.2.0, I enabled storyboard for launch screen:

```
<enable-launch-screen-storyboard>true</enable-launch-screen-storyboard>
```

I have the LaunchLogo image set (5 files) under app/assets/iphone ([as instructed](https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_SDK_5.2.0_Release_Note-section-46245011_TitaniumSDK5.2.0ReleaseNote-Storyboard-basedLaunchScreen)).

Works find on simulators and devices. But when I submitted it to the app store, I got this error:

> ERROR ITMS-9000: "Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5 - New
>   iPhone apps and app updates submitted must support the 4-inch display
>   on iPhone 5 and must include a launch image referenced in the
>   info.plist under UILaunchImage with a UILaunchImageSize value set to
>   {320, 568}. Launch images must be PNG files and located at the
>   top-level of your bundle, or provided within each .lproj folder if you
>   localize your launch images.

Anything I could miss or something wrong from Appcelerator's end? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out if your app supports iOS 7, you still need to provide iPhone 5 Launch Screen PNG files, besides the storyboard.

Or you can just drop iOS 7 support.

Answer (score 1):

This is all about app version...

Currently, if you support iOS 8, you still have to provide a launch image for a 4 inch device because 4 inch devices because they can update to iOS 8 and or above.

For example, my app supports iOS 8, but this means I support all devices which can update to iOS 8. This includes the following 4 inch devices.. iPhone 5, iPhone 5S, iPhone 5C, iPod Touch 5G and iPod Touch 6G.

To support this properly, go to LaunchImage, click on the Attributes inspector and select Portrait or Landscape under iOS 6 and Prior. Now add a 1x image (320 x 480 pixels). Now you are supporting a LaunchImage for 4 inch devices properly.

In the future, look at the iOS version you support, then look at which devices can update to that version and supply LunchImages for those devices. This will be helpful to determine supported devices https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices